# Unable to Automate Mail/Server Sync Using doveadm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dovecot, webmin, virtualmin

I'm trying to migrate emails using dovecot's: doveadm sync -1 command.

I have created a file of email addresses (usernames) that I'd like to iterate through and I can do this; however, each time I need to enter the root password for the receiving server.  I've gone through documentation for a few days now, but can't find anything to set this up without using IMAP syncing.  I'm just trying to automate a backup service for a second server to hold an archive.  Any direction is appreciated.

Here's the command I'm using (on the existing/working server): `doveadm sync -1 -u user@extension.com remote:mail2.myserver.com`

here's what comes up:

> root@mail2.myserver.com's password:

Once I manually type in the password, it works.

The issue is that I have dozens of email addresses and need to automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use 'remote:' as the remote mail server, doveadm is going to use the default command (ssh) to connect to the remote and run the commands, which is why it's prompting you for the password.  Other options allow you to specify a different remote command, and supposedly to connect to a remote doveadm port, though I've never been able to make that work.

You should try creating an SSH key for root (or, better, for your dovecot user) and installing this, so that ssh no longer prompts for a password.  Then you can fully automate the synchronisation.

If you can set up doveadm as a tcp service on the remote, you should be able to connect to that instead, passing the doveadm password on the commandline using -o, but as I said I haven't been able to make that work as yet

Comment: I've finally managed to make the doveadm remote sync work - the key points are that (1) you need to use native doveadm protocol, not http for the service; and (2) it cannot go via a director proxy.  This works a lot better as then you only need to pass the doveadm master password for the sync to work.